# TSQL round to half decimals

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, rounding

I want to round to the nearest half decimals (geo coordinates) to do some data visualization. In t-sql, is there a built in function to round to half decimals (if that is the term). Examples of desired result:

```
    1.1 > 1.0
    1.4 > 1.5
    1.6 > 1.5
    1.9 > 2.0
```

Comment: I don't know of any built-in function that does this. Can you give some additional examples like what does 1.25 and 1.3 round too? Maybe some one will know a simple way to do the math.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Just multiply by 2, round, and divide by 2.

```
select round(1.1 * 2, 0) / 2 -- > 1.0
select round(1.4 * 2, 0) / 2 -- > 1.5
select round(1.6 * 2, 0) / 2 -- > 1.5
select round(1.9 * 2, 0) / 2 -- > 2.0
```

[Round on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175003.aspx)

Comment: @AdamPorad: `round(1.29 * 2) / 2` gives `1.5`.

Comment: Thanks @Guffa and Thanks Tim Lehner for the example. I was rounding to 1 decimal place and then dividing. I'm still not sure how I did that math -- I must have done an extra rounding in somewhere.